# Is it possible to change the title of batch-file(CMD) from another batch-file(CMD)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I like to make little `batch-file` games now and then, and for this one I want the title to be animated. I can't figure out a way to change the title from another `batch` file (CMD). It would be nice if one of you could help me because it would be the finishing touch on this game.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the Windows' API. This is how to make a title bar changing program.

Create a file using notepad and call it `SetText.bas`. Store it on your desktop.

Paste this into it.

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Module MyApplication  

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Declare Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long

Sub Main()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim CmdLine As String
    Dim Ret as Long
    Dim A() as String
    Dim hwindows as long

    CmdLine = Command()
    If Left(CmdLine, 2) = "/?" Then
        MsgBox("Usage:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "ChangeTitleBar Oldname NewName")
    Else
        A = Split(CmdLine, Chr(34), -1, vbBinaryCompare)
        hwindows = FindWindow(vbNullString, A(1))
        Ret = SetWindowText(hwindows, A(3))

    End If
End Sub
End Module
```

Then type in a command prompt window.

```dos
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:winexe /out:"%userprofile%\desktop\SetText.exe" "%userprofile%\desktop\settext.bas" /verbose
```

A program has been created on your desktop called `settext.exe`. To use

```dos
"%userprofile%\desktop\settext" "Untitled - Notepad" "A Renamed Notepad"
```

Comment: not every one will have `v4.0.30319\vbc.exe` in their path